# How to make a DNS Server?

Tags: dns, webserver

How do I make my pc a DNS Server like `no-ip.com` so that I can target my own web sites?

Comment: Do you have a static IP address on the internet?

Comment: Are there any other computers on your network that need to use your PC for a DNS server? If not, simply add entries to your `hosts` file.

Comment: Why do u pepole vote down my Question? It is the very basic question for beginners.

Comment: @Farid-ur-Rahman From FAQ: "Super User is for _computer enthusiasts and power users_"

Comment: @techie007 - then? I think it is computer related Question.

Comment: Your question had absolutely no context, nor any useful information, for us to help you. Rephrase your question and provide sufficient information, and there's a good chance it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

A simple general answer for a non-specific general question:

1. Connect your computer to Internet with a non-changing IP address.
2. Install DNS server software, if none came bundled with your operating system.
3. Run said DNS server software.
4. ?
5. Profit!

Comment: I would like to add point 6) Party!

Comment: and one that definately needs research... and more information on his needs.